# Basic Calc - why can't I solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, normal-distribution, error-function

So a basic form of the Gauss error function is

$$\int e^{x^2}\,dx$$

and apparently this is not solvable analytically. But why? It seems that I can solve it pretty easily as

$$\int e^{x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2x}e^{x^2}$$

since

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2x}e^{x^2} = e^{x^2}.$$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: go review the rules of differentiation.

Comment: Have you learnt about the product rule?

Comment: If you apply the quotient rule and chain rule on the derivative for $\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x},$ you do not get $e^{x^2}$

Comment: As for the possibility of finding an antiderivative using elementary functions, you might be interested in Liouville's theorem (differential algebra), which can be used to prove certain functions do not have elementary antiderivatives (including $e^{-x^2}$): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: Note that this assumes a precise definition of what is an "elementary function". They consist of the rational functions, algebraic functions (like taking n-th roots, or more generally solutions to polynomial equations over $\mathbb{C}$), exponential functions (including complex exponentials which give the trig functions) and logarithms, and finally compositions of functions of the previous types.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck "The solution to that integral is the error function". Actually, it is the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) multiplied by a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ (plus the constant of integration).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you take the derivative of $$\frac{1}{2x}e^{x^{2}}$$ you need to use the product and chain rules.  You get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{2x}e^{x^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2x^{2}}e^{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{2x}2xe^{x^{2}} = e^{x^{2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^{2}}\right) \neq e^{x^{2}}.
$$